# Need a concise way to evaluate NULL when assigning IDataRecord values

Tags: c#, null

I have a FillDataRecord method that assigns values to an object from an IDataRecord.  It works until it encounters a field with a NULL value, at which point it breaks with the message, "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

The workaround is to use IDataRecord.IsDBNull, which I've done, but I'd like to make this cleaner.  Here is the code with some relevant comments.

```
private static Employee FillDataRecord(IDataRecord dataRecord)
{
    Employee employee = new BusinessEntities.Employee();
    employee.EmployeeID = dataRecord.GetInt32(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("EmployeeID"));
    // Other fields omitted for brevity...

    // This breaks when StreetLine2 is NULL.
    employee.StreetLine2 = dataRecord.GetString(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("StreetLine2"));

    // This is my first workaround, which fixes the above error but is verbose.
    if (dataRecord.IsDBNull(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("StreetLine2")))
        employee.StreetLine2 = "";
    else
        employee.StreetLine2 = dataRecord.GetString(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("StreetLine2"));

    // This is my second workaround, which uses a custom method shown below.
    // But it requires casting.
    employee.StreetLine2 = (string)setDataRecordSafely(dataRecord, "StreetLine2");

    // Other fields omitted for brevity...
    return employee;
}
```

Here is the method that I wrote to handle NULL values.  This gets called by the second workaround shown above.

```
public static object setDataRecordSafely(IDataRecord dataRecord, string fieldName)
{
    int fieldIndex = dataRecord.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
    bool isFieldNull = dataRecord.IsDBNull(fieldIndex);

    Type fieldType = dataRecord.GetFieldType(fieldIndex);
    switch (Type.GetTypeCode(fieldType))
    {
        case TypeCode.String:
            return isFieldNull ? "" : dataRecord.GetString(fieldIndex);
        case TypeCode.Int32:
            return isFieldNull ? 0 : dataRecord.GetInt32(fieldIndex);
        case TypeCode.Boolean:
            return isFieldNull ? false : dataRecord.GetBoolean(fieldIndex);
        // TODO: Extend to handle other types as required.
    }

    return null; // The type wasn't handled.
}
```

Is there a way to overload that setDataRecordSafely() method to return the appropriate System.Type so that I don't have to cast the returned value?  What I'd like to avoid is this type of casting within the FillDataRecord() method.

```
employee.StreetLine2 = (string)setDataRecordSafely(dataRecord, "StreetLine2");
employee.City = (string)setDataRecordSafely(dataRecord, "City");
employee.StateID = (int)setDataRecordSafely(dataRecord, "StateID");
```

Or, is there a better way to handle NULL when assigning column values via an IDataReader?  Thanks for your help.

=== Edit 12/31/2014 at 1:45 PM Central ===

Thanks @Rhumborl and @Jeff Mercado. I ran with the Extension Methods you suggested, and my solution is below.  Props for the paragraph 2 guidance you provided Jeff.  Here is my class.

```
public static class IDataRecordExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Extension that gets the field's string value, or transforms null into an empty string.
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetString(this IDataRecord dataRecord, string fieldName)
    {
        int fieldIndex = dataRecord.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
        bool isFieldNull = dataRecord.IsDBNull(fieldIndex);
        return isFieldNull ? string.Empty : dataRecord.GetString(fieldIndex);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extension that gets the field's int value, or transforms null into 0.
    /// </summary>
    public static int GetInt32(this IDataRecord dataRecord, string fieldName)
    {
        int fieldIndex = dataRecord.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
        bool isFieldNull = dataRecord.IsDBNull(fieldIndex);
        return isFieldNull ? 0 : dataRecord.GetInt32(fieldIndex);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Extension that gets the field's bool value, or transforms null into false.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool GetBoolean(this IDataRecord dataRecord, string fieldName)
    {
        int fieldIndex = dataRecord.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
        bool isFieldNull = dataRecord.IsDBNull(fieldIndex);
        return isFieldNull ? false : dataRecord.GetBoolean(fieldIndex);
    }

}
```

And here is the implementation, after importing the class namespace via a using statement.

```
public static Employee FillDataRecord(IDataRecord dataRecord)
{
    Employee employee = new BusinessEntities.Employee();

    employee.EmployeeID = dataRecord.GetInt32("EmployeeID");
    employee.FirstName = dataRecord.GetString("FirstName");
    employee.LastName = dataRecord.GetString("LastName");
    employee.Title = dataRecord.GetString("Title");
    employee.Email = dataRecord.GetString("Email");
    employee.StreetLine1 = dataRecord.GetString("StreetLine1");
    employee.StreetLine2 = dataRecord.GetString("StreetLine2");
    employee.City = dataRecord.GetString("City");
    employee.StateID = dataRecord.GetInt32("StateID");
    employee.ZipCode = dataRecord.GetString("ZipCode");
    employee.CountryID = dataRecord.GetInt32("CountryID");
    employee.IsDeleted = dataRecord.GetBoolean("IsDeleted");

    // Above is in lieu of this syntax, which doesn't handle null.
    // employee.Email = dataRecord.GetString(dataRecord.GetOrdinal("Email"));

    return employee;
}
```

Comment: I wrote some generic extension methods at work which I can't post for IP reasons. Basically it adds `.Read<T>(string col)` and `.ReadNullable<T>(string col)` to `IDataRecord` which do the `DBNull` checks and return `default(T)` if it is null or cast to the correct type if not. Something similar to that should let you handle almost any type without the slightly ugly explicit casts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a case where using extension methods and using appropriate names can make all the difference.

`setDataRecordSafely()` is a confusing name.  It implies that you are setting a value but you are actually getting a value.  Don't try to make a try-to-handle-all-cases method like you have there, make one for all the cases you want to support with the appropriate types.  You're not going to get type safety if you are simply returning `object`, you should return the most appropriate type.

Fortunately, the `IDataRecord` interface offers a general `GetValue()` method, you can use that instead of using the specifically typed getters.  And therefore can be generalized as a generic method.

```
public static T TryGetValue<T>(this IDataRecord record, string fieldName, T defaultValue = default(T))
{
    try
    {
        var index = record.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
        return !record.IsDBNull(index) ? (T)record.GetValue(index) : defaultValue;
    }
    catch // or do type/data checking
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

If the default value for the type is not good enough, you can add extra methods to feed in your preferred default values.

```
public static string TryGetString(this IDataRecord record, string fieldName, string defaultValue = "")
{
    return TryGetValue(record, fieldName, defaultValue);
}

public static int TryGetInt32(this IDataRecord record, string fieldName, int defaultValue = 0)
{
    return TryGetValue(record, fieldName, defaultValue);
}
```

Now your calling code can simply do this:

```
employee.StreetLine1 = dataRecord.TryGetString("StreetLine1");
employee.StreetLine2 = dataRecord.TryGetValue<string>("StreetLine2", ""); // or the generic version
employee.City = dataRecord.TryGetValue<string>("City"); // or use the default value
employee.StateID = dataRecord.TryGetInt32("StateID");
// and so on...
```